# Update array in mongoDB through my loopback application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

I am developing API using loopback + mongoDB. In that i have to update an array in a document in mongoDB:

My model:

```
{
  "userId": "546fgdfgd445",
  "rrrr": "7",
  "bbbbb": [
    {}
  ],
  "id": "57a437789521b58b12124016"
}
```

I need to update the array with new element with the data sent form client:

```
app.models.vvvvv.update({ userId: '546fgdfgd445' },{ $push: { "transactions": transactionData }}, function(err, res){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
```

But i am receiving error:

```
{ name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'The dollar ($) prefixed field \'$push\' in \'$push\' is not valid for storage.',
  driver: true,
  index: 0,
  code: 52,
  errmsg: 'The dollar ($) prefixed field \'$push\' in \'$push\' is not valid for storage.' }
```

I am using mongoDb version 3.2.3.

Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `transactionData` ?Seems there is something wrong with that.

Comment: @Shrabanee No..its perfect.. Its an object,,, I am trying to push object ({}) into athe array..\

Comment: Can you try doing this in mongo shell directly? I tried the way you have written and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

in `model.json` you need to enable extended operations like this :

```
"options": {    
    "mongodb": {
      "collection": "model_collection",
      "allowExtendedOperators": true
    }
  },
```

or

```
    app.models.vvvvv.update({ userId: '546fgdfgd445' },
{ $push: { "transactions": transactionData }}, { allowExtendedOperators: true }, function(err, res){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
```